# How to use DB::raw in eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently using eager loading in laravel and used the `select()` method. However, when I tried to select the child table, it returns an error. Please see my code below.

**Controller**

```
$posts = Post::with('author');

$posts->select(['body', DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) as AUTHOR')]);
```

The code above returns this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.first_name' in 'field list'

So I tried to make it like this:

```
$posts = Post::with('author');

$posts->select(['body', DB::raw('CONCAT(author.first_name, " ", author.last_name) as AUTHOR')]);
```

Now I used the relationship to get the first and last name but I'm getting the same error. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I'm using `laravel 5.2` for this project.

Comment: `'author.body'` or `'post.body'`

Comment: @sta I think the error is in the author side not on the post

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tackle this with:

```
$posts = Post::with('author:id,first_name,last_name')->get();
```

Based on [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns) you have to provide the column names of the relationship table as above. Don't forget to Add the "id" as well because it will not work otherwise.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2 version so I think I cannot use this one since it is not supported on this version. Any other way except using joins or join is the best way to do this?